# Starting a bootRun process on port 80 as non-root user with Spring

Tags: java, spring, tomcat, port

I'm trying to use Port 80 as a non-root user and I've seen the discussions about using IP Tables but I'd like to use the tomcat configuration files to be able to modify these bindings. There is an option for `AUTHBIND` that allows using ports <1024 but I have no idea where the Spring tomcat files are located... There is no tomcat service running when I start my Spring process so where is the Spring tomcat server actually located? Where can I see the configuration files etc?

Comment: are you using embedded tomcat?

Comment: @mohitsharma In my `build.gradle` file I have `spring-boot-starter-web` and `org.apache.tomcat.embed:tomcat-embed-jasper:8.0.23` so yes it's embedded but I have no clue on how to use it.

Comment: check my solution

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you have a wrong approach. I don't recommand you to try to use HTTP port 80 directly.

A good practice is to use [Apache HTTP Server](https://httpd.apache.org/) redirection or alias :

- Here's a [tutorial](http://code.tutsplus.com/articles/apache-aliasing-and-redirection--net-28606)

**Explaination :**

You will start your Tomcat with "classic" port (such as 8080 or 9080 or anything else over 1024). Then, you will configure your Apache server to redirect HTTP request from HTTP port 80 to your Tomcat server.

Comment: I tried doing it using `apache2` but it didn't seem to resolve the problem for whatever reason that the tomcat service isn't working as it's supposed to with it. Instead I'm using `iptables` to redirect traffic on port `8090` to `80` for both `80` and `443` which seems to be working. Probably not the best practice but I also think that using `nginx` may be a better option.

Comment: I'm not sure you can say that Nginx is better than Apache.It's just another HTTP server. It's different. But it's ok if you find a solution with iptables.

Comment: I'm not saying it's better, I find it to be easier to work with than apache, and there seems to be more questions about it as far as I've searched

Answer (score -2):

```
Do follow steps:
1. Go to your application.properties if it doesn't exist.
2. Create a application.properties inside src/main/resources folder.
 example->/src/main/resources/application.properties
3. Simply add this property  server.port = 80 or if you want it to be random do server.port = 0
```

Comment: `server.port = 80` cannot be used unless running as a privileged user on Linux. If it was the case that I could simply use port 80; I wouldn't have asked the question.

Comment: The question wasn't "Whats one way to set a spring-boot server to port 80?"